# Handling subequations with make4ht

Tags: svg, subequations, mathjax, make4ht

When compiling with `make4ht` and using `svg` parameter, the equation, drawn from `subequation` using `align` environment, is not converted into `SVG`. If I change to `mathjax`, the HTML displays the warning: `Unknown environment 'subequations'`.

Here follows a small sample to reproduce it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Test
\begin{equation}
H(X) = - \sum_x p_x \log p_x
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
A&=&B\\
D&=&C \label{e:middle}\\
E&=&F
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with:

```
make4ht -u -x test-math.tex "svg"
```

Changing to `eqnarray` works fine. Should I use a patch in a configuration file? I tried the following:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\renewenvironment{align}{
    \begin{eqnarray}
}{
    \end{eqnarray}
    \ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

Is it a bug in `make4ht`? Is there a better solution?

Comment: The patch above does not solve the problem when using ```mathjax```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MathJax doesn't support the `subequations` environment out of the box. I've found a [JavaScript code](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/8YxzxF-m_hM/m/CJCkceuoCgAJ) that should implement it, but I cannot get it to work.

You have few more options - first option is to use images, as you already do. Not all math environments are converted to images by default, but you can use options to require it. The option is usually named `pic-` + `environment name`. See [the documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html) for more supported options.  For example `pic-align` will work in your example:

```
make4ht -u -x test.tex "svg,pic-align"
```

Result:

[image]

Another option is to use MathML. It needs to be used together with MathJax, because not every browser has MathML support:

```
make4ht -u -x test.tex "mathml,mathjax"
```

Result:

[image]